# jquery.js:893 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem with the following code:

```
$(document).on('click','#add_free_ticket',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab_logic").append('<tr id="free_event_clone"><td class="form-group"><input type="text" name="free_ticket_name[]" class="form-control"></div></td><td class="form-group"><input type="text" name="free_ticket_avail[]" class="form-control"></td><td class="form-group"><select class="form-control" name="free_ticket_avail_to[]"><option value="0" selected>All</option><option value="1">Members Only</option></select></td><td class="form-group"><input type="text" name="free_ticket_frm_date[]" class="form-control datetimepicker1"></td><td class="form-group"><input type="text" name="free_ticket_to_date[]"  id="tmp2" class="form-control datetimepicker2"></td><td class="form-group"><input type="text" name="free_ticket_per_guest[]" value="1" class="form-control"></td><td><button class="del_free_ticket  btn btn-danger btn-sm">X</button></td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: You should not add an `on()` on `document` , take the frist element in the body for that.

Comment: Hi, JustOnUnderMillions things are working fine only creating problem with bootstrap datetimepicker, when choose date and time browser is getting hanged

Comment: Do you other event handlers within `javascript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys i got the solution for my question , after spending 3 days

Problem was with the fromvalidation io for dynamic added fields

```
on('success.field.fv', function (e, data) {
 if(data.field === 'postal_code' && !data.fv.isValidField('postal_code')) {
  data.fv.revalidateField('postal_code');
}
```

above code was creating problem for Maximum call stack size exceeded for this problem i have written the below code

```
callback: {
  message: 'Start Date and End Date can not be equal',
  callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
    var startTime = validator.getFieldElements('event_start_date').val();
    var endTime = validator.getFieldElements('event_end_date').val();
    if (startTime === endTime) {
      // The start time is also valid
      // So, we need to update its status
      validator.updateStatus('startTime', validator.STATUS_VALID, 'callback');
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Petter , you are right .. next time when i add anything i will consider it